# PHP - How do I expand all arrays within an array

Tags: php, arrays

My code is giving an error when I try to echo all values within an array but also expand and echo the values of any arrays in the original array.

```
while (list($key, $val) = each($bal)) {
     If (is_array($val)){
          while (list($k, $v) = each($v)) { 
               If (is_array($va)){
                    while (list($ka, $va) = each($va)) {
                         echo "$ka => $va\n <br>";
                    }
               } else {
                    echo "$k => $v\n <br>";
               }
          }
     } else {
          echo "$key => $val\n <br>";
     }
}
```

The error I am getting is

> Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\money\production\simalgorithm1.php on line 234

Line 234 is `while (list($k, $v) = each($v)) {`

Shouldn't this automatically not be an array as I did a check the line previous? My Syntax must be off I am fairly new to PHP if someone could help me see what I am not seeing I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Question should be closed as off-topic since it is about a simple typo and not likely to be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
while (list($k, $v) = each($v)) {
```

I think you want this

```
while (list($k, $v) = each($val)) {
```

EDIT: I would also point out that your code will not work if the arrays are nested more than a few levels deep.  You should consider defining a recursive function or using [var_export](http://php.net/var_export) or [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump).

Comment: That was it, thank you! Though as I go deeper I am realizing how deep this array goes and I will probably just make this recursive.

Comment: You've got some other errors too. E.g., you refer to $va before you ever define it.

Comment: Also, I'd seriously consider using foreach instead of list and each. The syntax has fewer parens, easier to type and read.

Comment: Yea, I noticed the other errors once you pointed out the first. If I use foreach how would I print the key?

Comment: I found the answer to that http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php Thanks again.

Comment: Does that mean you answered your question? If not, try the docs: http://php.net/foreach

Comment: Yea sorry, trying to get used to enter submitting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best one line problem solved.

print_r($bal);